# Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#app" returned null

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I just started to use Vue.js, I'm trying to trigger the muose click when I press the button. The message problem is: Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#app" returned null. This is the js script:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
     data(){
        return {
                        
        }
     },
     methods: {
      changeCard(){
          console.log('here')
      }
   }
})


app.mount('#app')
```

Here the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>   
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <nav class="navbar is-link has-centered-menu" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">

<div class="navbar-end">
            <a class="navbar-item">
              <div id="app">
                <ion-icon v-on: click="changeCard" name="notifications-outline" size="large"></ion-icon>
              </div>
            </a>
</div>
</nav>
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You get that error because the browser hasn't rendered to the dom the `div#app` at the time of executing your script. [Defer your script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) until after the document is parsed.

Comment: Okay got it, it's simpler than I expected, thank you so much